# How to sort a 2D ArrayList by column value, and what if the values are equal?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I want to sort two-dimensional `ArrayList` by their specific column values and if the column values of two arrays are equal then compare the two arrays using another column value.

For example:

```
array = [[2, 3, 4, 5][0, 2, 3, 4][0, 1, 2, 3][1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I want to compare them first with their index `[0]`, but since `array[1][0]` and `array[2][0]` have the same value `0` I want to compare these two arrays by their index `[3]`.

So, the new array would be:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3][0, 2, 3, 4][1, 2, 3, 4][2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I have this code

```java
public ArrayList<List<Integer>> sortArray(ArrayList<List<Integer>> spaces) {
    final Comparator<List<Integer>> comparator = new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<Integer> sList1, List<Integer> sList2) {
            return sList1.get(0).compareTo(sList2.get(0));
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(spaces, comparator);

    return spaces;
}
```

However, this only compares the value by the index `[0]`, and no condition when the values are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your `Comparator` to handle that index check something like this:

```java
public int compare(List<Integer> sList1, List<Integer> sList2) {
    if (sList1.get(0) != sList2.get(0)) {
        return sList1.get(0).compareTo(sList2.get(0));
    } else {
        return sList1.get(3).compareTo(sList2.get(3));
    }
}
```

But if you are running Java 8 and above you can directly do something like this to sort your collection:

```java
Collections.sort(spaces, (sList1, sList2) -> {
    if (sList1.get(0) != sList2.get(0)) {
        return sList1.get(0).compareTo(sList2.get(0));
    } else {
        return sList1.get(3).compareTo(sList2.get(3));
    }
});
```

For pre-Java 8 you can do similar to what you are already doing:

```java
Collections.sort(spaces, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<Integer> sList1, List<Integer> sList2) {
        if (sList1.get(0) != sList2.get(0)) {
            return sList1.get(0).compareTo(sList2.get(0));
        } else {
            return sList1.get(3).compareTo(sList2.get(3));
        }
    }
});
```

In both cases, the output will be:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Java Collections.List's compareTo method (Let's abbreviate CT). Here are some example outputs of CT. 5.CT(7) -> -1 ; 7.CT(5) -> 1 ; 5.CT(5) -> 0 ;
compareTo returns 0 when they're the same, so you simply don't swap their positions. I'm not sure if I'm answering the question correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare all items in sub lists. For example:

```java
public int compare(List<Integer> sList1, List<Integer> sList2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int c = sList1.get(i).compareTo(sList2.get(i));
        if (c != 0)
            return c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Not suggested if you are looking for a fast algorithm.